# Sqllite :Selecting records between 2 dates including intervening rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have some data in a sqllite db table (mytable ) of the form:

```
id  column1  date
111 280 2014-02-01
112 281 invalid invalid invalid
113 282 invalid invalid invalid
114 275 2014-02-01
......................
338 273 2014-02-28
```

I want to select all the records in February. There are some intervening records that are invalid and don't have a date. I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-03-01'
```

but this skips the intervening records

I want to select these as well, so that I end up with all the records between id 111-338

All the columns except for id are in text format.

How can I do this?

Comment: You need a rule how to substitute invalid date with correct date. What if table data's like `111 280 2014-02-01
112 281 invalid invalid invalid
113 275 2014-04-01`? Is invalid  BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-03-01' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't have sqlite right now but this should give you a start:

```
select max(id) as max_id, min(id) as min_id
from mytable
where date BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-03-01'
```

then

```
select * 
from mytable where id >= min_id and id <= max_id
```

I think this would make it in just one query:

```
select mytable.* 
from (select max(id) as max_id, min(id) as min_id
      from mytable
      where date BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-03-01'
) as internal, mytable 
where mytable.id >= internal.min_id and mytable.id <= internal.max_id
```